# Android contact view style

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, contacts

[Android contact view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCNaE.jpg)

I have a database with a column called `PoemTitle`, so I want to get the first letter from each title and give it a vector background with different colors.
Please, can anyone help me with a function to do so depending on the char type? Below is the code that I tried:

```
fun getHeaderFirstChar(poems:Poems, res: Resources) {
  when (poems.PoemTitle.first()) {
    'a'..'b' -> res.getbackground
  }
}
```

That is the code I tried but it's not working
Note: language is `Kotlin` and I'm using `RoomDatabase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't re-invent the wheel, have a look at this library:
https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable
[image]

and yes its Java but you can use it in Kotlin as well!

Comment: Please try to do some research on your own or you will never learn. If you look actually looked at the Github project is has a sample directory and inside there, believe it or not are examples using... wait for it... `RecyclerView`s. https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/amulyakhare/td/sample/ListActivity.java 